# How to enable JavaScript support in Links...?

Tags: javascript, linux, browser

When I run the c# app on the linux virtual machine on Azure, a request needs to be authorised by logging in to microsoft account,for which browser should have javascript support show up the microsoft login page on terminal so how do I enable javascript on links..?

[Use this link for the image of links screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnTSL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Javacript support is available if you compile from sources with `--enable-javascript`. Please check here http://links.twibright.com/user_en.html#ap-javascript